# add xml declaration in soap ws springboot project

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, soap, spring-ws

I would need the response of the provided service to have the xml declaration. i have searched but could not find a solution that i can integrate into my code.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

this is my code:

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
      public ServletRegistrationBean<Servlet> messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);

        return new ServletRegistrationBean<>(servlet, "/license/services/*");
      }

      @Bean(name = "License")
      public Wsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition() {
        SimpleWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new SimpleWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setWsdl(new ClassPathResource("/wsdl/avs_2.wsdl"));
        
        return wsdl11Definition;
      }
    
}
```

```
@Endpoint
public class WebServiceEndpoint {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebServiceEndpoint.class);
        
        @PayloadRoot(namespace = "http://license", localPart = "getContentInfo")
        @ResponsePayload
        
        @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.OK, reason = "OK")
        
        public JAXBElement <getContentInfoResponse> getRequest(@RequestPayload JAXBElement<getContentInfo> request) {

            ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();
            getContentInfoResponse response = factory.createGetContentInfoResponse();
            ResponseLicense responseLicense = factory.createResponseLicense();
            responseLicense.setPlayHoursRemained(23456);
            responseLicense.setPlaysRemained(-1);
            responseLicense.setResultCode(0);
            //responseLicense.setResultMessage("");
            response.setGetContentInfoReturn(responseLicense);
            
            JAXBElement<getContentInfoResponse> xml = createJaxbElement(response, getContentInfoResponse.class);
            
            return xml;
          }
    
          private JAXBElement <getContentInfoResponse > createJaxbElement(getContentInfoResponse response, Class<getContentInfoResponse> clazz) {
              
              JAXBElement<getContentInfoResponse> xml = new JAXBElement<getContentInfoResponse>(new QName(clazz.getSimpleName()), clazz, response);

              return xml;
          }
            
}
```

I get the response I need...

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/>
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<getContentInfoResponse xmlns:ns2=http://license>
<ns2:getContentInfoReturn>
<ns2:playHoursRemained>23456</ns2:playHoursRemained>
<ns2:playsRemained>-1</ns2:playsRemained>
<ns2:properties xmlns:xsi=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:resultCode>0</ns2:resultCode>
<ns2:resultMessage xmlns:xsi=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance xsi:nil="true"/>
</ns2:getContentInfoReturn>
</getContentInfoResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

but I would like the response header to carry the xml declaration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope ....
```

Comment: Where is your mashaller? You usually set the encoding there

Comment: I have no other classes the transition from xml to model (request) and from model to xml (response) is made in class WebServiceEndpoint.

Comment: The thing is your `JAXBElement ` has no idea what encoding should be used and it shouldn't have to care. Therefore usually when you serialize it the marshaller has the encoding and potentially the XML version, such that it is done the same across all objects marshalled with that marshaller so you do not need to repeat it